# Course Enrolment Date set to 1/1/1970

Tags: moodle

I have registered a new account and have an Enrolment key for the course.
I finished the course and after that I run cron.php  so that the results will reflect the report. 
But everytime I do that the Enrolment Date in the Report will be set to 1/1/1970

I looked up in the database and checked the mdl_course_completions and the timeenrolled is set to **0**.
I changed the data and it changes what is showing in the report in the Enrolment Date Column.

I created again a new account with the Enrolment key and finished a course and the Enrolment Date is again set to 1/1/1970

Is there a way to fix that? Please help. Thanks.

**Note:** The users that I have registered are using Enrolment key to enrol in a course.

I am using Moodle version: Moodle 3.0.7 (Build: 20161114)

[image]

Comment: Without knowing anything about moodle, I suspect that you've set the Enrolment Date [sic] to 0 - 1/1/1970 is the start of the Unix date epoch (aka the 0 date).  If you haven't done this explicitly, the date may still have been set to 0 by some initialization process, leading to the same result.